# ¿Cómo hago que highcharts abra los enlaces del tooltip en el navegador?

Tags: react-native, highcharts, programación-móvil, expo

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación React Native en expo. Una de las pantallas contiene un gráfico, en el cual hay una [descripción emergente](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20159/1674) (*tooltip*) con un cierto texto, al que querría añadirle un enlace.

Muy básicamente, la aplicación es:

```
import ChartView from 'react-native-highcharts';


render() {
        let Highcharts = "Highcharts";
        let config ={
            chart: {
                type: "line",
                animation: Highcharts.svg,
            ...
            tooltip: {
                followTouchMove: false,
                useHTML: true,
                formatter: function () {
                    return `<div class="text">BLA BLA BLA
                                <a href="http://www.google.cat">esto es un enlace</a>
                                    </div>`;
                }
            },
        };
```

Y luego se renderiza en:

```
    return(
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <ChartView
            config={config}
        />
```

Mirando en [Link inside of a Highcharts tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22427025/1983854) veo ideas interesantes como poner dentro de `charts` la info:

```
    events: {
        click: function (event) {
            var url = 'http://www.google.cat';
            window.open(url, '_blank');
        }
    }
```

Que funciona, pero me abre el enlace dentro del ChartView de React Native, y no en el navegador.

¿Existe alguna manera de abrir los enlaces directamente en el navegador? La manera estándar con React Native es usar `Linking.openURL(url);`, pero desde el highcarts no tengo acceso a `Linking`.

Comment: Y no hay forma  de que en vez de usar html puedas enviar un componente con la función de `Linking` bindiada?

Comment: @GermanAlzate algo así me gustaría hacer, pero hasta el momento no fui capaz. ¿Se te ocurre alguna manera?

Comment: Revisando el código, me parece que no hay alguna forma de lograr eso, ya que veo que lo que hace internamente es cargar el módulo web de highcahrts y ponerlo dentro de un `WebView`, lo cual no es como tal que hagas un render del componente y poder manipularlo con funciones nativas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo resolví usando `onMessage` en el CharView:

```
return(
<View style={styles.container}>
    <ChartView
        onMessage={m => this.onMessage(m)}
        config={config}
    />
</View>
```

Que lanza este método para abrir la URL:

```
onMessage = (m) => {
    let data = JSON.parse(m.nativeEvent.data);
    Linking.openURL(data.url)
};
```

Nótese que la URL se guarda mediante una variable global `window.myURL` y se pasa como mensaje con [`postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage):

```
render() {
    let Highcharts = "Highcharts";
    let config ={
        ...
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stickyTracking: false,
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function(e) {
                            window.postMessage(JSON.stringify({'url': window.myUrl}));
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
        },
        tooltip: {
            useHTML: true,
            formatter: function () {
                window.myUrl = extras.url;
                return `<div class="text">bla bla bla
                            <a href="http://www.google.cat">my link here/a>
                        </div>`;
            }
    };
```

Funciona bien en iOS. Para que lo hiciera en Android tuve que usar `window.__REACT_WEB_VIEW_BRIDGE.postMessage()` ([referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55742772/1983854)).